# When to use verbs in GraphQL query schema naming?

Tags: graphql, apollo

Almost always when I see GraphQL schemas, it's just an object graph.

However I have seen ["search" used as a verb on the tree](https://graphql.github.io/learn/schema/#union-types).

The example there has at top level:

```
hero
droid
search
```

Besides `search`, when else might it be appropriate to use a verb in the query tree?

And are there best-practice examples of using nested verbs?

(Naturally individual queries and mutations will use verbs extensively - this question regards only the query schema.)

Comment: could you explain what you mean by verb.  the example given could of been any name

Comment: @JoeWarner we usually reserve verb naming for functions.  Everything I've seen an a GraphQL schema has been nouns (hero, droid, widget, user, application) indicating that they are objects.  The only verb (action word) I've seen is "search".  Are there other cases where we might use an action word?  This makes that part of the schema seem more like a function (like `search()`) as opposed to a data requirement declaration like `application { address { state } }`.